# Create Backendless user after successful Google login

Tags: android, backend, google-signin, google-authentication, backendless

I'm starting to use `Backendless.com` `mBaaS` on Android
I sign in user via Google and I got token and everything is OK, but the logged in user isn't created an `Users table`, so I can not use it to store user specific data.

So I tried to combine user login from [here](https://github.com/Backendless/Android-SDK/tree/master/samples/LoginWithGooglePlusSDK) with user creation from documentation:

```
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    logined = true;

    loginInBackendless(result.getSignInAccount());

    BackendlessUser user = new BackendlessUser();
    user.setProperty("email", result.getSignInAccount().getEmail().toString());
    user.setProperty("name", result.getSignInAccount().getDisplayName().toString());
    user.setPassword(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    Backendless.UserService.register(user, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
        public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser registeredUser) {
                 // user has been registered and now can login
        }

        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
            // an error has occurred, the error code can be retrieved with fault.getCode()
        }
    });
```

the question is:
**Is it right way to create user?** it seems not OK, because every time google user is logged in, a new `Backendless` user is created (or his record in `Users` table is updated).

Comment: Backendless automatically stores user after successfull social (Facebook, Google+, Twitter) login. Maybe you receive any error?

Comment: No, in android monitor i see:
LoginFragment: handleSignInResult: success is true
LoginFragment: handleSignInResult: try login to backendless
LoginFragment: idToken: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZC<...>
I have modificated Users table by adding a pointer relation, but user is created with the method above

Comment: now I remowed all my user registration code and see this error:
LoginFragment: Could not login to backendless: Invalid social identity code: 9010
in github example they use WebKey for Google API, so did I. Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: Did you try code generation tool with Google+ login? You can follow steps that where made there.

Comment: @schaffe will try now, thank you

Comment: @theendcomplete can you provide your initial code so we can reproduce and fix this issue? You can post it on http://support.backendless.com/

Comment: @AnatoliiStepaniuk с вашей стороны нет никаких багов, просто пример с гитхаба, переделанный под меня, пользователя не создает
а генерация кода отработала очень хорошо, даже появилась поддержка двухфакторной аутентификации